# how to capture all regex groups but the last one?

Tags: regex

How do you convert camelCase text to uppercase underscore but remove the suffix?

If I have a text "AbcdEfghIjklAlphabet", how can I capture it so that the result will be "ABCD_EFGH_IJKL" with the suffix Alphabet gone?

Is it possible to do it with just regex?

Comment: Please show more context for your issue. What language or tool are you using, and are you trying to make a replacement, or a selection?

Comment: Do you know how to do it *without* suffix exclusion?

Comment: This needs to be done in Java

Answer (score 0):

You will have to "anchor" the back end of your target. A likely candidate for that is the "word boundary" zero-width assertion: `\b`

Once you know where the end of the match is located, insert a hard requirement for whatever-pattern at the end, and *don't capture it*. Something like this:

```
pattern = r'(capture-stuff-at-the-front)But-no-stuff-at-the-end\b'
```

Now you are capturing everything except the last word, or whatever. You just have to decide what the up-front stuff is, and what the various edge cases are. So:

1. If the first letter is lower case, like:  `isCondition` do you want that to match?
2. If there's just a single word, like:  `Heavy` is that a match?
3. Are numbers allowed, and if so should: `Rs232Cable` keep numbers with the front or back?
4. Et cetera. I'm sure there's stuff I haven't thought of...

So try this:

```
pattern = r'((?: uppercase-letter lowercase-letters*)+uppercase-letter lowercase-letters+\b'
```

That might match `PRPolicy` as well as `RequestPolicy` and capture everything but the last `Policy`.

```
import re
test = 'isCondition Heavy Rs232Cable PRPolicy RequestPolicy'
pattern = r'((?:[A-Z][a-z]*)+)[A-Z][a-z]+\b'

for m in re.findall(pattern, test):
    print(m)
```

Output is:

```
PR
Request
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple and can be done entirely in regex without looping if you're using a language with a robust regex engine such as Python.

Pattern: `([A-Z][a-z]*(?![a-z]*$))`

Replace: `\U\1_`

Explanation:

- `[A-Z][a-z]*` - Match a capital letter followed by any number of lowercase letters.
- `(?![a-z]*$)` - Assert that the characters matched with the above pattern are not followed by any number of lowercase letters and then the end of the string, to prevent the last group from matching.
- `(...)` - The entire pattern is wrapped in parentheses so that the match is captured for later.
- (Replacement) `\U` - Convert the output that follows to uppercase.
- (Replacement) `\1` - Output the value of the first capture group.

Comment: This works great independently but seems to have an issue with Java's replaceAll method. Any thoughts on that?